# Mostrar nombres, pero guardar id de un combobox python

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero que cuando seleccione un item de los combobox me imprima por pantalla el id, para luego ser almacenado en la base de datos en la tabla correspondiente, como puedo hacer eso?

Aqui lleno los combobox con los datos de la base de datos

```
        def emp():
            cursor = conexion.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT empresa FROM empresas")
            datoemp = cursor.fetchall()
            return datoemp
            cursor.close()

        def taman():
            cursor = conexion.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT tamano FROM tamano_precio")
            datotaman = cursor.fetchall()
            return datotaman
            cursor.close()

        def pic():
            cursor = conexion.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT pico FROM picos")
            datopic = cursor.fetchall()
            return datopic
            cursor.close()
```

Aqui se guardan los datos para ser imprimidos por consola

```
        def guardar():
            for cilindros, empresa, tamano, pico in lista:
                print("Cilindro ", cilindros)
                print("Propietario: ", guardarCedula)
                print("Empresa: ", empresa.get())
                print("Tamano: ", tamano.get())
                print("Pico: ", pico.get())

        ventana5 = Toplevel()
        cantidadVacios = cantidadCilindros.get() +1
        lista = []
```

Aqui se muestran los combobox

```
        for cilindros in range(1, cantidadVacios):

            titulo = tk.LabelFrame(ventana5, text= f"Cilindro {cilindros}")
            titulo.pack()

            empresa = ttk.Combobox(titulo, width=11)
            empresa["values"] = emp()
            empresa.current(0)
            empresa.pack()

            tamano = ttk.Combobox(titulo, width=11)
            tamano["values"] = taman()
            tamano.current(0)
            tamano.pack()

            pico = ttk.Combobox(titulo, width=11)
            pico["values"] = pic()
            pico.current(0)
            pico.pack()

            lista.append([cilindros, empresa, tamano, pico])

        Button(ventana5, text="Guardar", command=guardar).pack()
```

De antemano muchas gracias por las molestias PD: Antes de esta parte del codigo, el usuario lo que hace es colocar cuantos cilindros quiere registrar, y de acuerdo a lo que vaya a registrar se muestran en pantalla la cantidad de combobox correspondientes

Comment: El ciclo funciona perfectamente, solo que quiero que al seleccionar un item del combobox me salga es el Id del producto

Comment: Calidad uso del bucle for de python, no conocía esta características del lenguaje.

Comment: ¿Porque no le agregas un evento al combobox y sacase el id por la pantalla?